# If statement inside command line

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to create a shell script and the fact is, I want to change the output if the variable `$output` is filled. I was thinking about checking the variable with an `if` inside the command but I don't know if it's the correct syntax. Here is an exemple (of course that doesn't work):

> ls -lisa | awk '$5 == own' own="$owner" | sort -k$column -n if [
>   $output ]; then print > out.txt fi

I don't know if it's going to work that way and if it's possible.

Comment: You could use `if test $output` to check if it is not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exec built-in can change the default standard output for the rest of the running shell script.  So, in this case, you would do:

```
if [ -n "$output" ]; then
    exec >out.txt
fi
ls -lisa | awk '$5 == own' own="$owner" | sort -k$column
```

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do with the awk part, so this is just verbatim from your question.

Another option is to put the part of your script that you want to redirect into a function, and then call the function in one of two ways, redirecting the output.  Example:

```
do_work() {
    ls -lisa | awk '$5 == own' own="$owner" | sort -k$column
}
if [ -n "$output" ]; then
    do_work >out.txt
else
    do_work
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the shell's "use default value" option (`${variable:-default}`, with /dev/stdout as the default) to do this:

```
ls -lisa | awk '$5 == own' own="$owner" | sort -k$column -n > "${output:-/dev/stdout}"
```